# What is a ready to use tool I can use to code survey comments

Tags: nlp, azure-cognitive-services, survey

I want to code a large number of survey responses that are extracted from a website, I want to use a tool that uses (natural language processing)NLP for text classification and sentiment analysis. I reviewed Microsoft Cognitive and while it seems decent product in the semantic area I am not sure how good it is in text classification. is there is any hustle free tool out there that I can integrate into the website and does the coding automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know , Azure text analysis provide ways about Sentiment Analysis,Key Phrase Extraction,Language Detection and Named Entity Recognition only, text classification is not supported as a out of box function. But you can use Sentiment Analysis function to get a [sentiment score](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-sentiment-analysis#concepts) to classify your surveys based on your requirement.

Btw, you can use Azure Machine learning to meet your text classification requirement too. This is a [ML Text Classification Template](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2015/05/06/azure-ml-text-classification-template/) offered by MSFT expert .